# PHP MySQL find, count and order results by count

Tags: php, mysql

I have query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
           FROM global_info 
           WHERE title LIKE '%$string%' 
              OR tag   LIKE '%$string%' 
              OR body  LIKE '%$string%'";
```

How can I count number of results for each row and then order results based on count?

For example
Row 1:

Title:

> Nice photo of Adricatic sea

Body:

> This is me and my friend at the Adriatic sea, somewhere in Montenegro.
>   Color of Adricatic sea is amazing.

Tag:

> Adriatic sea, photo

Row 2:

Title:

> Adricatic sea

Body:

> Take at noon

Tag:

> Adriatic sea, photo

And someone search:

> adriatic sea photo

Row 1 have more results than row 2, and it will be on the first place in the query result.

Comment: Actually, you'll get no results searching `LIKE '%adriatic sea photo%'` on the sample data given as none of the columns shown contain that exact phrase.

Comment: not sure if it's possible outside php (in a sql query only) but you can use php count() and check how many results are selected in each categories.

Comment: You'd be better off using a FULLTEXT index and ordering by the relevant score. What you want via LIKE comparisons will result in hideously ugly queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can use.

One is to use full text searches - which will take you in a different but very helpful direction. Read about it at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html.

The other approach is to infer it using strength length changes when you do a text substitution:

```
(LENGTH(`body`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`body`, 'Adricatic', '')))/LENGTH('Adricatic')
```

Of course, you'd substitute "'Adricatic'" with the variable holding the word searched for by your user. And you would repeat for each field you want to contribute to the score. Sum the scores and you've got your results.